# File upload cross browser issue

Tags: html, css, input-type-file

Tradiationally we make use of  `<input type="file">` for uploading a file but this element doesn have a consisitent behaviour across different browsers like firefox and chrome.It appears as just a button on chrome and on firefox it appears as a text field along with a file upload button.
    The CSS solution that i employed for overcoming this issue is as follows:

```
HTML:

    <div class="fileinputs">
    <html:file name="importForm" property="formFile" styleClass="file"/>
    <div class="fakefile">
    <input/>
    <input type="button" value="Browse"/>
    </div>
    </div>

CSS:


div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
}

div.fakefile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.file {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This solution solves the inconsisitent behaviour but the selected file is not getting displayed in the file input field.How do we overcome this issue?

Comment: *How do we overcome this issue?*: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: but in my case i hav to make it look the same in both chrome and firefox....